# Representation options of strings (keywords/topics) in models

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, topic-model, javascript

What are all the possible ways to represent keywords in a machine learning model?

The two I am aware of are:

- one hot encoding, using a static index.
- vector representation, using
  an embedding layer.

We have a specific problem where we are doing client side (browser) ml and need to convert text data into something the model can consume without sending it over to the server.

EDIT: (comment clarification)
The text data is extracted from the page on which our script loads, we then want to run a model locally on the browser - using text based features from the page (ideally). We are minimising in all elements any data needed to sent to the server.

In terms of model, that is not defined at this stage, also this question primary concerned with representation of text based features.

Comment: Please clarify the client-server setting and what kind of ML is used. Also it's important to know if the keywords are extracted from the text or predefined.

Comment: For plain sentences, have you tried word embeddings like Word2Vec or GloVe? Additionally there are new models for converting English words to vectors using transformers like BERT and ELMo which are context based(each vector for each word differs depending on the context of the sentence). Maybe check it out?

Comment: @Erwan edited answer.

Comment: @IronEdward Yeah I know all these approaches, but they need huge models stored on servers to convert words -> vectors.

Comment: @dendog thanks. but are you going to train a model or predict based on an existing model on the client side? (or both?) That changes whether you can have a predefined vocabulary or not. Anyway, in general a word is a categorical variable so the smallest possible representation is an index in a predefined array, like one-hot-encoding.

Comment: @Erwan yes both train & predict on the client.

Comment: @dendog by "run the model locally" I assume that you mean applying a model to predict something, right? it's still not clear where the model would come from? or do you mean that the model is also trained locally before being applied locally? And what is the goal of the model, extracting the keywords?

Comment: @Erwan We would create a dataset locally on the client, and then send a model lets say logistic regression `sig(X*W+b)`, where the X is the local data. However I feel we are very much deviating from the question, I am just interested in how I can encode text data into something mathematical models can understand.

Comment: Well since the question mentions the client/server issue I assumed that it was relevant, especially because whether the model is pre-computed or not determines whether the vocabulary (keywords) are predefined or not. It also depends a lot on what kind of model and what kind of task: as I mentioned above, for traditional models (e.g. log reg) words are encoded as categorical variables and simply stored in a lookup table. It's also very common to filter common/uncommon words for efficiency and/or accuracy, but that depends on the task being carried out.

Comment: Appreciate your help @Erwan, do you know any other ways than those listed in the question?

Comment: In general I can't see any other option than as an index when treating the word as a categorical variable or a vector of some kind, the two options that you already know. However there are many variants and parameters for the vector option, especially about the dimensionality, but that would depend on the task. For example in topic modeling you can represent a word as a vector where each value is the conditional probability of topic N given this word, but that's only one example among many.

Answer (score 2):

Since (word-based) one-hot encoding and real-valued vector representations are already mentioned in the question, I would only add the n-gram representation, especially the character-based n-gram representation.

For word-based [n-gram representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model#N-gram_model) you consider not individual words, but their ordered combinations in the text and use the one-hot encoding for the combinations. E.g. for n=2 you might end up with the bigrams ["John likes", "likes to", "to watch", "watch movies"] and each of them would be assigned to some dimension using a static index.

This also works with characters, so you can represent the word "encoding" e.g. with those 3-grams: ["enc", "nco", "cod", "odi", "din", "ing"]. The one-hot encodings of n-grams are typically added, so multiple occurances of the same n-gram are recognizable in the resulting Bag-of-n-grams representation. This kind of representation is especially useful for languages with rich [morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_(linguistics)) and/or [compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)) words. In a one-hot representation each single word form would be encoded in its own dimension whereas a character n-gram approach helps preserve similarity between different forms. An example in the English language would be the similarity between "encode", "encoded" and "encoding" which would stay preserved this way. Similar techniques are also used by some word embedding algorithms which consider subword information like e.g. [FastText](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04606).

Also, although it's not directly an encoding, but depending on your use case and language it might be worth looking at different preprocessing options like lemmatization and stemming where you reduce different word forms to their base form. This would also affect the choice of representation, e.g. the word-based one-hot encoding might make more sense if you choose to use these preprocessing techniques.